# MySQL update all the strings that start with same prefix but deleting only the part that starts with an underscore

Tags: mysql, sql

In the column `value` of table `image` of a mysql database I have a lot of different url of images.
They all have the same prefix `prefix-` followed by `5 different characters and numbers`, for example:

```
prefix-SD356
prefix-RV954
prefix-UB347
```

Unfortunately after that, I alway have an `underscore` followed by `other characters, numbers and underscore` which I would like to delete but keeping the first part.

To better understand:

this `prefix-SD356_2_25.jpg` should become `prefix-SD356.jpg`

this `prefix-RV954_1.jpg` should become `prefix-RV954.jpg`

this `prefix-UB347_1_1.jpg` should become `prefix-UB347.jpg`

and so on...

I would need a query where I can update all the string that begin with `prefix-` `[A-Za-z0-9]` keeping that part and delete the rest that starts with `_`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you say:

```
select concat(left(string, 12), '.', substring_index(string, '.', -1))
```

This is easily incorporated into an update:

```
update t
    set string = concat(left(string, 12), '.', substring_index(string, '.', -1))
    where string like 'prefix______%.%';
```